# Disable CSS text selection programmatically

Tags: javascript, css

This is seemingly a duplicate, but read on for it is not quite so... I think... :) I have followed the answer here: [How do I disable text selection with CSS or JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3779534/how-to-disable-text-selection-with-css-or-js) with a twist. I want to disable the selection programmatically for certain fields, and I do that in [Chrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome) with:

```
node.style.webkitUserSelect="none";
```

Which works fine. However, I tried the following for Firefox:

```
node.style.mozUserSelect="none";
```

But this doesn't work. I haven't tried with any other browser. Is there a different way to do this? And is it a "documented standard" that all CSS rules like this:

```
.rule {
    some-css-selector: value;
}
```

is translatable to JavaScript like the following?

```
node.style.someCssSelector="value";
```

Or is it just luck that it happens to work in some cases?

Comment: Try doing this on a few other browser specific css3 style attributes. I think user select is something that is implemented so differently between browsers. For instance, try this for border-radius and let us know what you find. Hopefully that will provide some insight to this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With prefixed properties the prefix starts with a capital letter, so `node.style.MozUserSelect="none";`

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks! For the record, I also changed the crome specific code to node.style.WebkitUserSelect="none"; and it still works. So like you say, prefixed properties should start with a capital letter, it just seems like chrome was a bit more tolerant..

Answer (score 2):

One option, is to create a CSS style and then programmatically add that class to the items you desire:

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
  This is some text that should not be selectable!
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.noselect {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
```

**JS**

```
var container = document.getElementById("container");
container.className += " noselect";
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PpBwb/)

Comment: Ah, that is clever... However, in this particular case, for various reasons, which may or may not be well thought through, I would like to refrain from relying on classes in a CSS file.