# How do I make it impossible to highlight text using CSS?

Tags: css, text, highlighting

I am trying to make a website.  I made a header using tables, and when you highlight it it looks tacky.

```
.topmenu::selection 
    {
    background: rgba(255,79,79,0); /* Change highlight color */
    }
```

I call it by using `<div class="topmenu::selection">` in the PHP.  Am I calling this code incorrectly?

Thanks!

EDIT:
This didn't quite seem to work. I am working with expression engine if that makes any changes. here is my work so far:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset={charset}" /> <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/Flame.ico" />
 <title>New Hope Christian College</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/nhcc-css/text.css" /> 
<center> 
<table width="960" border="0" div class="topmenu">

.topmenu {
    FONT-SIZE: 12px; COLOR: #000000;
    FONT-FAMILY: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.topmenu::selection {
    background: transparent;
}
.topmenu::-moz-selection {
    background: transparent;
}
.topmenu a {
    color: #A71137; text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
    COLOR: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Essentially, I have a table, I want the header (which is a table) to be "unselectable" and the rest of the body to be selectable.

This one did it for me!

It's possible in CSS3 user-select property:

CSS

```
.element{
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

You can also add cursor:default; on the :hover peuso-element.

Example with a table and a thead

http://jsfiddle.net/swAmt/2/

Comment: Try this link it requires multiple lines:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/826782/css-rule-to-disable-text-selection-highlighting][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/826782/css-rule-to-disable-text-selection-highlighting

Comment: Don't make your header using tables, make it using `DIV`s.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3779534/how-to-disable-text-selection-with-css-or-js and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/826782/css-rule-to-disable-text-selection-highlighting and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326004/prevent-selection-in-html

Comment: Is that your unedited markup?  Because it looks like you either have a table in your head element (which isn't allowed) or head elements (title, etc.) in your body element (which also isn't allowed).  Also, deprecated center tag, deprecated table attributes, etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's possible in **CSS3** `user-select` property:

### CSS

```
.element{
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

You can also add `cursor:default;` on the `:hover` peuso-element.

**Example with a table and a thead**

**http://jsfiddle.net/swAmt/2/**

Comment: This one did it for me!
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Change it to:

```
<div class="topmenu">
```

`::selection` is a *pseudo class*. It's not something you actually *assign* to something. `.topmenu::selection` means *"whenever the `.topmenu` element is being selected"*.

Answer (score 0):

There really isn't any way of achieving this.  What you can do, however, is make it *appear* as if highlighting is disabled with CSS by removing the background-colour that would otherwise be applied.

It's not yet fully-supported so you have ot use differing vendor prefixes, but essentially this will do (at least part of) what you're after:

```
::selection {
    background: transparent;
}
::-moz-selection {
    background: transparent;
}
```

Do bear in mind that these are [pseudo-class selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#pseudo-class-selectors), and don't make up part of the class itself in your markup.

If it was just `.topmenu` that you wanted to apply this to, your markup would look like this:

**HTML:** `<div class="topmenu">`

**CSS:**

```
.topmenu::selection {
    background: transparent;
}
.topmenu::-moz-selection {
    background: transparent;
}
```

Comment: This didn't quite seem to work.  I am working with expression engine if that makes any changes.
here is my work so far:
`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset={charset}" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/Flame.ico" />
<title>New Hope Christian College</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/nhcc-css/text.css" />


<center>
<table width="960" border="0" div class="topmenu">`

Comment: `.topmenu {
    FONT-SIZE: 12px;
    COLOR: #000000;
    FONT-FAMILY: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.topmenu::selection {
    background: transparent;
}
.topmenu::-moz-selection {
    background: transparent;
}
.topmenu a

{
color: #A71137;
text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover

{
COLOR: #000000;
text-decoration: none;
}`

Comment: Essentially, I have a table, I want the header (which is a table) to be "unselectable" and the rest of the body to be selectable.

Comment: @JaredTillford You should edit that into your question, not into the comments. It's hard to follow in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

In the html, change the DIV class to:

```
<div class="topmenu">
```

I also seem to have a problem highlighting the text with

`background: rgba(255,79,79,0);`

Try using another value other than 0, such as

`background: rgba(255,79,79,0.5);`